# How can i write a promise in Client Side

Tags: javascript, promise, hover, client-side

I don't know I have searched a lot and when I apply the code the console pop up with errors with a lot of things undefined I want to write a simple promise

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
            $('.hover-effect').on('click',function(event){
                    filters.forEach(function(vertical){
                        $("div[data-filter=" + vertical + "]").removeClass("selected");
                    })
                        $(this).addClass('selected');
                        const datafilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                        $(".verticals").hide();
                        $('#'+datafilter).show();

                });

            });
```

once the for loop is completed then i have to add the class selected and other things

Comment: tell me whats wrong with the question after marking me down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(event){
            $('.hover-effect').on('click',function(event){
                 const datafilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');    
                 var promise=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                     filters.forEach(function(vertical){
                            $("div[data-filter=" + vertical + "]").removeClass("selected");
                     });
                     resolve('success');
                 });    
                 promise.then(function(value){
                    $("div[data-filter=" + datafilter + "]").addClass("selected");                          
                    $(".verticals").hide();
                    $('#'+datafilter).show();
                  });

                });
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is unclear, it looks like you have a list of buttons with the hover-effect class, when clicked all other buttons should have their selected class removed and the clicked element should have the selected class added.

This part of your code works great:

```
const datafilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$(".verticals").hide();
$('#'+datafilter).show();
```

With that said I am pretty sure this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
$(document).ready(function(event){

    $('.hover-effect').on('click',function(e) {

        $(".hovereffect").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        const datafilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $(".verticals").hide();
        $('#'+datafilter).show();

    });

});
```

**Note:** If you are using the "hovereffect" class elsewhere you should create a new class to implement this functionality.

Comment: Using a class to select your buttons will also increase your performance in comparison to a foreach loop. In this code example, you would iterate through every "div" on your page to find any "div" with the matching data-filter and would do so for every filter you provide. Given a large pool of filters and elements on your page this could get somewhat intensive.